# append div does not work

Tags: jquery, html

I have this button with a div tag

```
<div class='test'>
    <button class="bt1">add statment</button>
</div>
```

I want to append the div by jquery bellow it the function

```
$(".test").on("click", ".bt1", function () {
    $(".test").append("<p>Statement: <input type='text' name='statement"+ i +"'><br><button class='deleteCon'> Delete</button></p>"); 
    i++;
});
```

Any one can tell me what is the problem?

Comment: where is this i coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `i` is not declare on the scope:

```
var i = 1; //Declare
$(".test").on("click", ".bt1", function () {
            $(".test").append("<p>Statement: <input type='text' name='statement"+ i +"'><br><button class='deleteCon'> Delete</button></p>"); i++; });
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t4FTX/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using append correctly but it appears that `i` was not defined.

See the following javascript:

```
var i = 0;
$('.bt1').on('click', function() {
    $('.test').append("<p>Statement: <input type='text' name='statement"+ i +"'><br><button class='deleteCon'> Delete</button></p>");
    i++;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xg5Bu/